# Having trouble running a command as another user on Ubuntu

Tags: sudo, root, command, su

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.  When logged in as root, I'm tryhing to run a command as anotehr (postgres).  However, it is failing

```
root@remotebox:/home/rails/myproject# su - postgres 'pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main'
-su: pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass `'pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main'` to the default shell for postgres user.
Depending on postgres user configuration this may mean to execute `'pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main'` file in postgres PATH, and this is the reason you get a "No such file or directory error".

Try pass the argument as a command (-c):

```
su - postgres -c 'pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main'
```

as a shell:

```
su - postgres -s /path/to/pg_upgradecluster -- 9.3 main
```

or to explicit choose the shell:

```
su - postgres -s /bin/bash -- -c 'pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main'
```